# assigning dynamic URL in getJSON

Tags: jquery, getjson

The alert stat `url123` shows the correct URL as assigned to the variable. If I give a static URL in `getJSON` otherwise it does not show the alert also and just column headers of grid are shown.
The complete code works fine if I hardcode the URL in `getJSON`.
I tried `.done()` also, but it is not working for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var globalObjMetrics=[];
var url123 = "http://" + hostname + ":" + port + "someservlet"; 

$.getJSON( url123, function(objJson) {
alert("in json" + url123);
     $.each(objJson, function() {
        var objMetrics= this['metrics'];
        topLevelMetricRender(objMetrics, this['name']);
    });

});

$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){alert('double clicked');}});


var topLevelMetricRender = function(objMetric, parentMetricName) {

    ... some code };



});
```

Comment: It means the URL isn't correct.  Either the string concatination isn't turning out to what you expect it to be, or the URL you are pointing to doesn't respond with what your code is expecting.

Comment: this is how i am getting value for variable url123 = function (){
var _url ;
if(typeof QueryString.hostname === "undefined" ){
_url = "/someservlet?output=json";
alert("in function" + _url);
}else {
_url = "http://" + QueryString.hostname + ":" + QueryString.port + "/someservlet?output=json";
alert (_url);}
return _url;

}();

Comment: I don't really care how you're getting the value for the variable, you just need to ensure you are getting what you expect.  There isn't a reason for the URL to fail if the hard coded string is the same as the one that's generated by your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see the alert message at all you're not getting a response for your request, the success function (your second parameter) is not being called. check if variable url123 and static url are identical.

Comment: I cross checked the value in variable url123 and static url are identical. So we may need to think some other solution